# Microsoft Graph API - PHP Curl single quotes

Tags: php, curl, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to query events from a group calendar using a cURL request in PHP and I need to get a specific date range (i.e. this month only). The problem is that anytime I use a filter with single quotes, I get a "Bad Request" error. The same string however works fine in the Microsoft Graph Explorer.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/12345/events?filter=start/dateTime ge '2022-10-01T12:30:00' and end/dateTime lt '2022-11-01T12:30:00'
```

I have no issues reaching any other endpoint as long as I'm not using a filter with single quotes. I've tried using curl_escape as well as manually encoding the string and I keep getting "Bad Request".

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the php code as well

Comment: You may also try this API to fetch the query events from a group calendar with the time range: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look up [url encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode)

```
urlencode("start/dateTime ge '2022-10-01T12:30:00' and end/dateTime lt '2022-11-01T12:30:00'");
```

returns

```
start%2FdateTime+ge+%272022-10-01T12%3A30%3A00%27+and+end%2FdateTime+lt+%272022-11-01T12%3A30%3A00%27
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. It turns out slashes don't translate through curl_escape like they do in urlencode.